# " check if Table is exist or not in database " is not working

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to make a java program can call a table by its name... but the problem is I couldnt figure out how to check if the table is exist or not in database... I am using phpmyadmin data base and here is my code if there is someone can help me ...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLxJ0.png)

```
public boolean istableNameexist(String un){
    boolean uexist = false;
    Connection con = myConnection.getconnection();
    PreparedStatement ps;
    ResultSet rs;
    try {
        ps = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM `javacontactapp` WHERE TABLE_NAME = ?");
        ps.setString(1,name.getText());
        rs = ps.executeQuery();
        if (rs.next()){
            uexist = true;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("wrong");
    }

    return uexist;
}

public void openfatura(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
    String ff1 = name.getText();
    Connection con = myConnection.getconnection();
    if (!name.getText().isEmpty()) {
        if (istableNameexist(name.getText())){
            try {
                PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("SELECT `dafat`, `sinif` ,`number` , `price`, `type`, `total` FROM " + ff1 + " WHERE `id` = 1");
                ResultSet resultset = ps.executeQuery();
```

Comment: You can query from `information_schema.tables`

Comment: it worked thank you